# How does git-merge deal with binary files

Tags: git

Let's consider this situation:

```
      o---o---o      slave
     /         \
o---o---B---o---o    master
```

I have a bunch of binary files. Some of them did not change in either `slave` or `master`, some other changed on `slave`.

During the merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge slave
```

Git showed me this:

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: foo.bin (HEAD vs. foo)
Auto-merging: foo.bin
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.bin
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Analysis:

`foo` changed on both sides. I agree that Git ask me to solve the conflict. However, `bar` changed only on the `master` and Git didn't ask me anything. He decided to take the change from `master` while I wanted him to consider `slave` instead.

How can I have a better control on how git merge binary files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git did not ask anything because you made the change on `foo` and you should be aware that this change will goes straight after the merge if nobody changed this file on the `slave` branch.

Let's go trough this simple example:

```
  o-- slave
 /   \
o--o--o master
^ origin
```

You can reproduce it with this:

```
git init
dd if=/dev/urandom of=foo bs=100k count=1
dd if=/dev/urandom of=bar bs=100k count=1
git add .
git commit -m "Added binary files foo and bar"
git branch origin

git checkout -b slave
dd if=/dev/urandom of=foo bs=100k count=1
git commit -m "Modified foo" .

git checkout master
dd if=/dev/urandom of=bar bs=100k count=1
git commit -m "Modified bar" .
```

Once you are read do do the merge, you will probably do:

```
git checkout master
git merge slave

Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 foo | Bin 102400 -> 102400 bytes
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

You notice that git noticed the change about foo but nothing about bar. It's because bar did not change on the `slave` branch.

If you wish to keep the bar from `slave`. You need to prevent git concluding the merge for you. You can do this:

```
git checkout master
git merge slave --no-commit
git checkout slave bar # I want to keep bar from slave
git commit -m "Commit successuful"
```

Later you can check if everything is ok:

```
git diff --stat master~1 origin
git diff --stat slave origin
git diff --stat master slave
```

I hope it clarifies a bit...